# Can someone explain to me, how to render FlexDashboard file to html?

Tags: html, r, flexdashboard

I have already made a FlexDashboard for a another person.  The owner of the dashboards wants it as a html file, because the dashboard is just part of a web system like WordPress or something. I don't have any access to their word press system, so I want to give them a html file.  Hopefully my question is simple:

Can someone explain to me, how to render FlexDashboard file to html?
I can supply the Dashboard file if needed to render it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try regroup the rendered element into a modal form and create some button so you can switch between your dashboards without refreshing the whole page.